# Can't install Rails (Windows )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

all day can not understand.
There are many tips online, but I'm confused.
maybe something wrong edited.

help me understand and find the error.

Ruby downloaded here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167&release_id=46722
was established.

then installed gem: http://rubygems.org/pages/download

then try install Rails,- 
wrote in concole:  `gem install rails`

but have error! -

Error: While executing gem ...

Invalid argument - C:/Documents and Settings/Neo/C:

this is my concole :

`C:\Documents and Settings\Neo>_`  - Does not a long way?

maybe I must heve only: `C:\>_`  ??? how I can do it?

my gem.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET _HOMEDRIVE=%HOMEDRIVE%
SET _HOMEPATH=%HOMEPATH%
SET HOMEDRIVE=С:
SET HOMEPATH=/Ruby193
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "С:/Ruby193/bin/gem" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
SET HOMEDRIVE=%_HOMEDRIVE%
SET HOMEPATH=%_HOMEPATH%
```

I either missed something or done something extra ...    Thanks!!!

Comment: I would look at  using http://railsinstaller.org/ if you want to install rails on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Installing RoR on Windows can be a real challenge when you try to install each piece individually. There is the [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) which will install everything you need. However, if you decide to install everything by yourself you can follow this procedures:

- Install the [ruby language](http://rubyinstaller.org/).
- Check if the installation was successful by checking its version:

  ```
  ruby -v
  ```
- Then you need to check if you can access gem command by checking its version:

  ```
  gem -v
  ```
- Update the gem version:

  ```
  gem update --system
  ```
- Having the ruby language and the updated gem, you can now instal the Rails:

  ```
  gem install rails
  ```
- You can check the rails version:

  ```
  rails -v
  ```
- Now you need the SQLite database:

  ```
  gem install sqlite3-ruby
  ```

Comment: I will try install from this link: http://railsinstaller.org/                                             I must download and install all of this elements?                                                                      Packages included are:

    Ruby 1.9.3-p125
    Rails 3.2
    Bundler 1.0.18
    Git 1.7.6
    Sqlite 3.7.3
    TinyTDS 0.4.5
    SQL Server support 3.3.3
    DevKit
maybe someone can help me with Skype? (sergey_49274)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing  error during rails installation  in **windows** >

**Solution :**

Download  Ruby+Devkit exe file
Install Ruby+Devkit

```
> ruby -v 
> gem -v
> gem install rails 
> rails -v
```

All worked !!!!